# Cumulative SUMIFS not working

Tags: sumifs, cumulative-sum

I use `SUMIFS` to calculate a cumulative total of time spent on different work projects in a table. The formula is:

```
=SUMIFS([Session Hours],[Project],"="&$C5,[Date],"<="&$A5)
```

Where column A is the Date field, and column C is the Project field. (It seems I can't attach a sample... Maybe I'm missing something?)

But I have a problem. I frequently work on the same project in two different sessions on the same day - and my `SUMIFS` function adds all sessions to the *end* of that day, not just to the current row.

I tried various ways of adding in a condition based on the ROW function, but Excel always claimed there was an error in the formula (there wasn't as far as I could tell). Then I tried adding in an `INDEX` function to specify that the range to be summed went from row 1 of the table to `[@Current Row]`. This returned a "VALUE" error message.

So, I'm stumped... Any ideas?

This is for MacOS, and the Excel build is 15.33.

Many thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

When working with Excel tables, there are two types of references, structed and explicit. You are using the [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) syntax for the formula, this is equivalent to passing in the entire column.

To get around this, you can convert your formula to use explicit ranges.

For example, if "Session Hours" is in column `D` then replace `[Session Hours]` in your formula with something like `$D$2:$D5`.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for this, but for some reason it doesn't work. I altered the formula to =SUMIFS($F$2:F2,[Project],"="&$C2,[Date],"<="&$A2) where the F column is Session Hours, and Excel returns #VALUE! all the way down he table except for the very last cell in the column, which adds correctly. I wish I could upload the example, but no idea how to...

Comment: Ah. Should have thought of this earlier: here's the file... <https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sp6a1no519so2v/Timesheet%20TEST.xlsx?dl=0>

Comment: You need to do the same for `Project` and `Date`.

Comment: Hmmm... So, now I have =SUMIFS($F$2:F2,C2,"="&$C2,A2,"<="&$A2) - and only the first line works! (I've saved the revised sheet - same link as before.) I really appreciate your help oaths, and also your patience. I'm clearly doing something stupid, and it's really kind of you to help.

Comment: Oops - got it!    =SUMIFS($F$2:F3,$C$2:C3,"="&$C3,$A$2:A3,"<="&$A3)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I would - but I can't figure out how!